# Spock: PollingConditions expect exception to eventually be thrown

Tags: groovy, spock

I'm trying to use `PollingConditions` to expect that an exception will eventually be thrown.

```
then:
 new PollingConditions(timeout: 3, initialDelay: 0.1, delay: 0.1).eventually {
  sasClient.getSASToken(pod, targetServiceType)
  thrown(NotFoundException)
 }
```

but this causes Groovy to complain with: `Groovyc: Exception conditions are only allowed as top-level statements`

Is it possible to test that an exception will eventually be thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe GroovyAssert can help you, try this:

```
new PollingConditions(timeout: 3, initialDelay: 0.1, delay: 0.1).eventually {
  GroovyAssert.shouldFail(NotFoundException) {
    sasClient.getSASToken(pod, targetServiceType)
  }
}
```